# Liberty on Vagrant

Tags: vagrant, websphere-liberty

I have a Vagrant Cent OS server. I've installed WebSphere Liberty and it's listening on port 9080. I've also installed Apache Tomcat to help me identify where the issue might be. Below is my Vagrantfile config showing the port forwarding Apache Tomcat works without issue and I can get to tomcat through from my desktop browser. But, trying to go to Liberty I get the error:

```
ERR_SOCKET_NOT_CONNECTED
At a loss
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 9080, host: 9080
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8080, host: 8888
```

Comment: netstat/lsof on the guest?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the *host* attribute on the *httpEndpoint* element is set to *** in your server.xml:

```
<httpEndpoint id="defaultHttpEndpoint"
              host="*"
              httpPort="9080"
              httpsPort="9443" />
```